# Error in Component Output by Button Click

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 buttons and information about div. When I click on one of the buttons, one component should appear in the div info. Where is the error in the withdrawal of the component div info?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Donald from '/.Donald';
import John from '/.John';

class Names extends Component {
  state = {
    array:[
      {id:1,component:<Donald/>, name:"Me name Donald"},
      {id:2,component:<John/>, name:"My name John"},
    ],
    currComponentId: null


   changeComponentName = (idComponent) => {
    this.setState({currComponentId:idComponent});
   };

   render() {
    return(
      <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr className="content">
        {
         this.state.array.map(item=> item.id===this.element.id).component
        }   
       </tr>
          <button className="Button">
            {
              this.state.array.map( (element) => {
                return (
                  <td key={element.id}
                    className={this.state.currComponentId === element.id ? 'one' : 'two'}
                    onClick={ () => this.changeComponentName(element.id)}
                    >{element.name}
                  </td>
                )
              }) 
            }
          </button>  
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

export default Names;
```

Comment: Cant understand what you trying to ask ?  ```Where is the error in the withdrawal of the component div info ?```

Comment: No idea what are you asking for, but you have no defined `changeComponentName` method there.

Comment: say what now? ?

Comment: The component is not displayed in the div info (I have information in the component)

Comment: There is only one button, state object has no proper ending, and how are you getting this.element.id.

Comment: change {element.name} to <element.component/>

Comment: There are some error in your code, 1. Missing this `}` in state object, 2. map always returns an array change this `this.state.array.map(item=> item.id===this.element.id).component` to `this.state.array.map(item=> item.id===this.element.id)[0].component` @GregoriRoberts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here, the first being that you are missing the closing curly bracket on your state. `this.element.id` is also undefined, I assume you are meaning `this.state.currComponentId`.

Your html is also fairly badly messed up, for example you are inserting multiple `<td>`s into the content of your button. I also don't see where `this.changeComponentName()` is defined, so I am assuming you mean `this.showComponent()`

The primary issue is probably in `this.state.array.map(item=> item.id === this.element.id).component`, as map() returns an array. An array.find() would be more appropriate, though you still need to check to see if there is a match.

I might re-write your component like this (I have swapped out the confusing html for basic divs, as I'm not sure what you are going for here)

```
class Names extends Component {
  state = {
    array: [
      { id: 1, component: <span>Donald</span>, name: "Me name Donald" },
      { id: 2, component: <span>John</span>, name: "My name John" },
    ],
    currComponentId: null,
  };

  showComponent = (idComponent) => {
    this.setState({ currComponentId: idComponent });
  };

  render() {
    //Finding the selected element
    const selectedElement = this.state.array.find(
      (item) => item.id === this.state.currComponentId
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content">
          {
            //Check to see if there is a selected element before trying to get it's component
            selectedElement ? selectedElement.component : "no selected."
          }
        </div>

        {this.state.array.map((element) => {
          return (
            <button
              className="Button"
              key={element.id}
              className={
                this.state.currComponentId === element.id ? "one" : "two"
              }
              onClick={() => this.showComponent(element.id)}
            >
              {element.name}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors:- (1) You are showing list inside  tag, instead show as `<ul><li><button/></li></ul>`
(2)`You are not displaying content after comparison in map()`
This is a working solution of your question.

```js
class Names extends React.Component {
  state = {
    array: [
      { id: 1, component: <Donald />, name: "Me name Donald" },
      { id: 2, component: <John />, name: "My name John" }
    ],
    currComponentId: null
  };

  clickHandler = idComponent => {
    this.setState({ currComponentId: idComponent });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.array.map(element => {
            return (
              <li key={element.id}>
                <button
                  className="Button"
                  onClick={() => this.clickHandler(element.id)}
                >
                  {element.name}
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        {this.state.array.map(data => {
          if (this.state.currComponentId === data.id)
            return <div>{data.component}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Donald = () => <div>This is Donald Component</div>;
const John = () => <div>This is John Component</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<Names />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```